# Python with etc/Shadow

Tags: python, linux, encryption, sha512

so I'm writing this program that needs to check the password hash in etc/shadow and compare it to the password the user entered. I tried encrypting the password with hashlib.sha512, but the result was not the same. I think it's salted some how, but I don't know if it uses a universal salt or how I can get the salt each time.

tldr; I need a way for a user to enter a password, then have the program hash it and check it against the etc/shadow. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe accessing the shadow file isn't called for. Can't you use your operating system's API to try to log in the user (as you have username and password)? When you can log in, the credentials are good, if not, well they're not.

Comment: Also, `/etc/shadow` shouldn't even be readable to a normal user.

Answer (score 4):

Try this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pam . First link in google by `python pam`.
Look at distribution package manager for python-pam if exists. Else install with `pip` or `easy_install`.

Small example:

```
>>> import pam
>>> pam.authenticate('fred', 'fredspassword')
False
```

Comment: Not sure why this one is down voted - I think its the best solution. No su/shadow/hash trickery and works on servers that use different auth mechanisms. Maybe an example is needed? `import pam;pam.authenticate('fred', 'fredspassword')`.

Comment: @user1377480, Have You traceback? How you did install this?
Maybe missed dependencies or not  compatible library versions.

Comment: I have no CentOS in my park.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import crypt
>>> line = 'bob:$1$qda8YAO9$rBiov9uVJlH1/97cbcyEt.:15965:0:99999:7:::'
>>> encript = line.split(':')[1]
>>> encript
--> '$1$qda8YAO9$rBiov9uVJlH1/97cbcyEt.'

>>> i = encript.rfind('$')
>>> salt = encript[:i]
>>> salt
--> '$1$qda8YAO9'

>>> crypt.crypt('bob_password',salt)
--> '$1$qda8YAO9$rBiov9uVJlH1/97cbcyEt.'
>>> encript
--> '$1$qda8YAO9$rBiov9uVJlH1/97cbcyEt.'
```

Answer (score 2):

The passwd field is not just a SHA-512 hash of the password.*

This is explained in the [`crypt` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html). The format is `$id$salt$hash`, where `id` specifies the hash method (1 for MD5, 2a for Blowfish, 5 for SHA-256, 6 for SHA-512), `salt` specifies the salt to use with that algorithm, and `hash` specifies what the result should be.

As the manpage implies, you can actually pass the whole `$id$salt$` to the `crypt` function in place of the `salt`, and it will automatically use the appropriate algorithm. This wouldn't be too hard to do via, say, `ctypes`.

---

At any rate, what you're doing is almost certainly a bad idea. You'll need to run as `root` in order to have access to `/etc/shadow`, and you'll need to simulate more than just password verification if you actually want to verify that the user can log in, and of course you'll need to handle secure input and make sure you don't end up saving the password in plaintext somewhere and so on. It's a lot simpler and safer to just let [PAM](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?libpam+3) do the work for you.

---

* I believe that in theory, it *can* be—if it doesn't start with a `$` it's interpreted as some legacy format… presumably meaning it's interpreted as POSIX `crypt` using the DES algorithm.